# Basic jQuery understanding

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the `event`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").click(function(event){
     alert("Thanks for visiting!");
   });
 });
```

and also this one

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").click(function(){
     alert("Thanks for visiting!");
   });
 });
```

these two JS blocks are doing the same thing, but one with an `event`, if someone could explain what is `function(event)`, also I saw something like function(e),function(g), what are those? Is there a tutorial I could learn?

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback function that you're providing to `$("a").click` is a function that takes an argument. This argument is an event object containing details about the object. Your function declaration can take this argument with any name you like — `event`, `e`, `g`... and it can also simply leave it out since you're not using it inside of your function.

Consider that these two functions are essentially the same:

```
function foo(hi) {
   alert(hi);
}

function foo(bye) {
   alert(bye);
}
```

And that you may leave out the argument if it's not used:

```
function bar() {
   alert("hello!");
}

bar(12345);
```

Answer (score 2):

Event is an object that represents the... **event** that produced that function to be executed.

Here's more information about the topic:

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

It is often used to prevent default behaviour of a certain event, or to stop the propagation of the event to parent objects:

```
function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `event` in the first example is an unused argument.

jQuery passes various arguments into each event handler - you can find details of what these arguments are in the documentation (e.g. http://api.jquery.com/click/).

As you do not need to use the `event` object (or `e`, or `g` - you can give the parameter any name you want) then it doesn't matter whether or not you include it

However, if you needed to use the handler for some reason (e.g. to call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default click behaviour from happening) then you would need to include it.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery passes eventObject to the handler/callback function which is not used in your example.
You could read [more](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) about the eventObject in JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

**Events** : An event in JavaScript is something that happens with or on the webpage.

**Example of events:**
A mouse click

The webpage loading

Mousing over a hot spot on the webpage, also known as hovering

Selecting an input box in an HTML form

A keystroke etc...

**Events in Jquery**

Using e is just a short for event.You could use any variable say g instead of e

```
 $('#xyz_id').click(function(g){
   var clicked_target = g.target;
 });
```

You could have a look at events in jquery further at

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 0):

event argument is a optional parameter and it can be any valid variable name. Based on your requirement you can pass or ignore it.

Visit http://api.jquery.com/click/ for more info.

```
.click( handler(eventObject) )

handler(eventObject)A function to execute each time the event is triggered.
version added: 1.4.3.click( [eventData], handler(eventObject) )

eventDataA map of data that will be passed to the event handler.

handler(eventObject)A function to execute each time the event is triggered.
version added: 1.0.click()
```